# Quicksort infinite loop in Java

Tags: java, infinite-loop, quicksort

I am trying to implement the quicksort algorithm in Java. The following code is identicall to the one provided by my university professor. It works just fine, until I set as an input the Object[] {1,2,3,14,24,5,454,1,24,2,11} (obviously left = 0 and right = 10). The algorithm seems to fall into an infinite loop, but I cannot find where or why. I have been looking at it for a few days now and i cannot find the bug. I studied other similar problems with the quicksort algorithms on the site, but they did not help in fixing my problem. I would apreciate any ideas.

```
static int partition (Object[] a, int left, int right, Comparator c){
    Object pivot = a[left];
    int i = left+1; 
    int j = right;
    while (i<=j){
        while(i<=j && c.less(a[i],pivot)){i++;}
        while(c.less(pivot, a[j])){j--;}
        if (i<j){
            Object temp = a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    a[left] = a[j];
    a[j] = pivot;
    return j;
}

static void quickSort(Object[] a, int left, int right){
    if(left<right){
        int p = partition(a,left,right, new Comparator());
        quickSort(a,left,p-1);
        quickSort(a,p+1,right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?  For small input that often help.  Also you should try strategically placed calls to `System.out`, these can be faster to debug than using a debugger.

Comment: It occurs when `i == j`. Both the first two while loops fail as well as the `if` statement so they are left unchanged. Try changing the main loop to `while (i < j)` and see if that works.

Comment: And my own implementation uses a `do ... while` for the outermost loop, to make sure the inner code runs at least once.  Might double check that as well.

Comment: I tried using `System.out.println(j)` at the end of the if statement. It print 6, then 8, then 6 again and then it falls into the infinite loop. But I cannot see why.

Comment: A true life saver. I did not think to doubt that, as it was given by the professor. Will not happen again! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to mark it as accepted answer, as markspace pointed out in the comments, the infinite loop occures when `i == j`. The two `while` loops fail as well as the `if` statement so they are left unchanged. Changing the main loop to `while (i < j)` fixxed the issue. Thank you, markspace, for your help!